# How to access child element <h2> and change background color

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, parent-child

[INPSECTION OF HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulR0.png)
Hi!

I've Googled and tried different things but I can't get this to work. Hoping someone here could explain what's wrong with my code.

I work with a learning management system and to change how things look, I need to make custom code.
In this case, I can find the ID based on the inspection on the website. My problem seems to be accessing the child that I need to change.

Appreciate any help.

This the code I tried. Accessing the parent work, but I get confused why the second line when trying to access the child. On the third line I don't get the option to change style because most likely something wrong with second line.

```
let parentOfMyTraining = document.getElementById('assignedTrainingWidget');  
let correctChild = parentOfMyTraining.firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling;
//correctChild.style.fontColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector` to find your `<h2 >`

e.g.

```js
// Find the first h2 inside the element with the id 'assignedTrainingWidget'
let correctChild = document.querySelector('#assignedTrainingWidget h2')
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Alternatively you can find all of the h2s then do something with the array of them with `document.querySelectorAll`.

```js
// Find the all h2s inside the element with the id 'assignedTrainingWidget'
let h2Array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#assignedTrainingWidget h2'));
let correctChild = h2Array[0]; // zero index is the first
let secondH2 = h2Array[1];
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm.

Do you know how I could access let say "the second" h2 element or simply just any of the children in an easy way? This code solved this problem, but going forward I have to access different childs that's not always the first.

Thank you agian.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a way to find more h2s. I recommend learning about "CSS selectors" and how they are used with `document.querySelector{All}` they're very powerful and are one of the best ways of finding (selecting) DOM nodes from the tree